# Can I customise the install4j Welcome screen messages?

Tags: install4j

I'd like to be able to set the message the Welcome screen shows when my installer starts? Is that possible?

If not, and I replace the Welcome screen with a Banner screen, will I loose functionality provided by the Welcome screen?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Go to the "General Settings->Languages" step and set up a custom localization file. In the editor for the localization file add a line

```
WelcomeLabel3=Your text
```

With the "Override message" tool bar button you can search for messages.

Comment: How can I do if I have arguments in my message using Install4j V.5 ?

Comment: It's the same procedure for install4j 5

Comment: I meant if you have a message with placeholders like so: `WelcomeLabel3=Your text {0} another text {1}`. How would I resolve the placeholders with a value stored in a prop file ?

Comment: It's not possible to add placeholders to system messages, you have to specify the entire message. However, you can use installer variables, like this: `${installer:myVariable}` and define the installer variable with `context.setVariable("myVariable", "value");` If you have follow-ups please ask a new question, because this is a different topic.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was about to ask you if I should open a new thread. I'll try what you suggested, and get back to you!

Comment: I opened another thread here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61223673/install4j-is-there-a-way-to-override-the-welcome-message-with-a-text-containing